# Auto close Dialog with cancel response after timeout

Tags: java, timer, javafx, javafx-8

I have implemented javaFX-Dialogs by taking the help of the Oracle Documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html

and the tutorial
http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

So far I have done the following things:
I have added a timeline in the dialog window.

```
public static void idleness(final DialogTemplate template) {
    System.out.println("timeline Started -" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Timeline idlestage = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(15), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            template.hide();
        }
    }));
    idlestage.setCycleCount(1);
    idlestage.play();

}
```

Now Dialog Window is hiding after 15 sec but not able to get any Dialog response.

Expectation:
 If user doesn't give any response within a given time, then negative response have to be recorded and dialog windows should get closed.

Comment: You can edit the question, and correct that. Also correct the "Dialouges". Link the tutorial you have followed. And what is DialogTemplate?

Comment: What do you mean by "negative response"? What is DialogTemplate? How does it look like?

Comment: it should give response of  cancel button while it closes automatically.

Comment: Instead of hiding the dialog, get the cancel button from the dialog, or the `DialogTemplate`, whatever that is, and [fire](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#fire--) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the result directly is working.

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{
    Scene scene = new Scene( new Group(), 200, 300 );

    Alert alert = new Alert( Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION );
    alert.setTitle( "Confirmation Dialog" );
    alert.setHeaderText( "Look, a Confirmation Dialog" );
    alert.setContentText( "Are you ok with this?" );

    System.out.println( "timeline Started -" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() );
    Timeline idlestage = new Timeline( new KeyFrame( Duration.seconds(5 ), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {

        @Override
        public void handle( ActionEvent event )
        {
            alert.setResult(ButtonType.CANCEL);
            alert.hide();
        }
    } ) );
    idlestage.setCycleCount( 1 );
    idlestage.play();

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

    if ( result.get() == ButtonType.OK )
    {
        System.out.println( "ok clicked" );
    }
    else if ( result.get() == ButtonType.CANCEL)
    {
        System.out.println( "cancel clicked" );
    }

    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```